# cocos2d-x V3.1 save screenshot to album for android

Tags: android, save, cocos2d-x, screenshot

I'm new for cocos2d-x and I'm using v3.1.
I wrote an app using cocos2d before and now I want to add an android version by cocos2d-x.

After checking online, I use this code for saving my screen image:

```
void Game1::takePhoto(Ref *pSender){

Size size = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();
RenderTexture* texture = RenderTexture::create((int)size.width, (int)size.height);
texture->setPosition(Point(size.width, size.height));
texture->begin();
Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene()->visit();
texture->end();
if (texture->saveToFile("screenshot.png", kCCImageFormatPNG)){
    CCLOG("screen captured");
}
```

}

Where did the file be saved? I can't find it on my album, how can I save it to album for android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it saved to where `getWriteablePath()` returns.

Comment: But how can I save it to Android device's gallery ( album)? Is it possible to do this by C++ using cocos2d-x?

Comment: You are on the right track. http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Save_a_Screenshot

Comment: I get a log showing my image is safe as " /data/data/com.xxx.xxx/files/screenshot.png"

But how can I save it to gallery? Should I call java code for this action? or I can use C++ to do it? I searched for cocos2dx forum and stack overflow..... seems nobody can answer this question.... Can you help? Thanks

Comment: I don't currently develop for Android, but I think you need to call: `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle , yourDescription);`

Comment: i tried  
`cpp: auto fullPath = FileUtils::getInstance()->getWritablePath() + fileName;`

JAVA:

`Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
  File f = new File(filePath);
  Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
     mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
     me.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);`

But I still can't see the image on my gallery, any hints?